# Assigning object to ivar when already assigned to that particular ivar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

In a situation where I am assigning an object to an ivar which the object may already be assigned to, is there any benefit to first checking whether it is already assigned to that ivar.

For example, is there any benefit to code **A** over code **B**?

## A

```
if (ivar != anObject)
{
    ivar = anObject;
}
```

## B

```
ivar = anObject;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not strictly necessary, I believe the @property/@synthesize generated setters do this as an optimisation and to stop unneseccary memory management calls on the same object (for a strong property the old object is released and the new one is retained, but if they are the same pointer the end result is the retain count is unchanged)

Comment: In addition to memory management methods the check will also prevent unnecessary KVO notifications from being made.

Comment: @BenedictCohen i dont think thats true. KVO notifications are sent in a subclass's implementation of the setter, so they dont know if the actual value was changed

Comment: Yes, you're correct. My bad. `@synthesize` doesn't fire the KVO notifications, they are handled by `NSObject`. If automatic notification is turned off (with `automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:`) then the `@synthesize`d properties do not raise KVO notifications.

Comment: Also, in MRC releasing the old object before retaining the new one will result in premature deallocation if it's the same object. (unless, of course, the retain count is greater than 1) This is more serious an issue than emitting redundant retain/release calls.